# Input field accept integer or float. And that result is 24.00 or (24) but not above 24

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#"+time_type_id+"_sun").keypress(function(e) {             
   if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && parseInt($("#"+time_type_id+"_sun").val()) > 25 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
     return false;
  }            
});
```

How should find total input value is less then 25. And Text field accept integer or float. If it is integer max input length is 2(Ex:- 24) or if it is float Max input length 5(Ex:- 24.00).

Comment: should not enter the value above 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. Instead of handling the `keypress` event, you can handle the `input` event (which deals with any change made to the content of the text field), then check whether the value entered is greater than the numeric value 24:

```js
$("input").on('input', function() {
  var value = +this.value;

  if (typeof value != "number" || value > 24) {
    $(this).val(24);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number here" />
```

Here if you enter a value which isn't numeric or is greater than 24, the value will be forced to 24. If you want to force the value to `24.00` instead, you can use `$(this).val('24.00');`.

For reference, `+this.value` uses the Unary Plus to convert `this.value` to a numeric value (similar to how `parseInt` works).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if ((e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46) && ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) || parseInt($("#"+time_type_id+"_sun").val()) > 25)) {
        return false;
}
```